# How to extract each TIFF layer to a separate file (png/jpg)?

Tags: linux, windows, tiff

I have TIFF files with tens of layers - is there a quick way to extract each layer to a separate png or jpg (so one 100 layer TIFF turns into 100 separate jpg's)?

TIFF created in AutoDesk Sketchbook if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ImageMagic `convert` command:

```
convert multipage.tif[0-99] single%3d.png
```

Here `%3d` is C `printf` style and will print `single001.png`, `single002.png` and so on.

If you want `single1.png`, `single2.png` and so on you can use the command in this way:

```
convert multipage.tif[0-99] single%d.png
```

You can try also with GIMP and [Export Layers plugin](https://github.com/khalim19/gimp-plugin-export-layers) as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/485929/680869)

In case of problems with layers of TIFF will be good to try to export it as PSD (Adobe Photoshop format) and try again with GIMP.

Comment: I tried the command but it didn't work as expected - it created one .png which contains both layers. Some warnings were returned as well:
`[root@cent610min ~]# convert 2layerTiff.tif single%3d.png`
`convert: 2layerTiff.tif: unknown field with tag 50784 (0xc660) encountered. 
TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/715.` `convert: 2layerTiff.tif: unknown field with tag 50784 (0xc660) encountered. 
TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/715.`

Comment: is layer the same thing as page?

Comment: No exactly. WIll edit my answer about the layers

Comment: @Flamd453, now `convert` should read the layers

Comment: still the same output as before I'm afraid

Comment: @Flamd453, add link about gimp

Comment: @rome-ninov that doesn't work either but the issue seems to be the Autodesk TIF files - when I open them in GIMP just one layer is detected, while when I open it in Autodesk Sketchpad all layers are shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105080/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-flamd453).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to talk in chat but it does seem it's an Autodesk problem: _Only use Autodesk SketchBook to read TIFF files containing layers. We do not advise you to open these images in other programs because we cannot guarantee layer preservation._ I'll try to raise it with them.

Comment: OK, exporting it to .PSD from Sketchbook and then using Gimp's export layer plugin you suggested works (finally!). Feel free to add that note to your answer and I'll mark it as the solution. And thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Flamd453, done, note added :)